# Using CORS to handle reauthentication on another site

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, single-page-application, siteminder

I'm trying to handle reauthentication using a different Authorisation website, while within a Single Page Application (SPA) in my home website.  Both websites are internal to a client site.

I can't use the standard "redirect" method as I'll lose my SPA JavaScript context.

I've investigated and had CORS setup on the Auth website so it's now returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.mywebsite.com`.  When I try to load the Auth page into a JQuery UI dialog it fails as the scripts all try to load in the context of the Home website.

i.e.
From my website `https://www.mywebsite.com/static/`
I'm loading `https://www.auth.com/login.html`.

When loaded into a JQuery UI dialog it tries to load it's scripts as `https://www.mywebsite.com/static/scripts/authscript.js`
instead of
`https://www.auth.com/scripts/authscript.js`

I also tried loading the Auth page into an `iframe` by changing the `src` tag but it just reloaded the page.

Is there a way to change the Source directory in the context of the CORS web page I'm trying to show?

Comment: Have you used relative paths for your scripts?

Comment: In the Auth page - they're not my Scripts.  And yes they're relative paths.  I'm hoping there's a way to change the "Origin" as that's effectively what I thought I'd done by using CORS.

Comment: You should open it in new window.

Comment: Been trying to avoid that as it's a poor user experience e.g. need to disable popup blocker if not triggered from a button push (in this case we're in an AJAX call).  Users running fullscreen miss the other window etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I couldn't get the page to load correctly into a standard jQuery Modal dialog and I have no control over the Auth page I was connecting to.  To solve this I investigated the problem I was having with the `iframe` and used an HTML5 feature `sandbox` to fix it.

The Auth page was using a "break out" script to reload the page if it was loaded into an `iframe` and obviously this broke my SPA context.  HTML5 allows you to restrict the contents of an iframe.

`<iframe src="" id="my_auth" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>`

- `allow-forms` Allow `form` and `submit`
- `allow-scripts` let it run JavaScript
- `allow-same-origin` let it consider the Origin the same as the script (i.e. the Auth website), this was necessary to enable cookies
- Of note is that I am not including `allow-top-navigation` which is what was allowing the reload of the page and loss of my JavaScript context

Voilà, auth page displayed inside a jQuery modal dialog (containing the `iframe`) with no need to pop up another window.

CORS was necessary to allow the redirect to the Auth website (which happens in the browser before JavaScript gets involved).  You could also trap the "Access-control-allow-origin" exception instead.

The iframe with the Siteminder login was accessing a page from my site that set a value in localStorage once the user had logged in.  The app just polled localStorage in the background to see if the user had logged in successfully.

Hope this is useful to someone.